# Extract year portion from date-string column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am new to Pandas

I am accessing the date column  which is in the format of

```
Restaurent    ISSDTM
CREAMERY INC 4/5/2013 12:47
CREAMERY INC 4/5/2013 12:47
SANDRA       3/5/2009 11:23
SANDRA       8/26/2009 13:11

print(df['ISSDTTM'].dtype)--> Is an object
```

I want to do a count plot for this as per the year.
I tried using the 
`df1=df['ISSDTTM'].apply(lambda x:x.split('/'))

to access the date but I am unable` to split the space in between. Also,

```
df1=df['ISSDTTM'].apply(lambda x:x.split(['/',' ']))
```

didn't work.

I also tried to access the last 4 digits using the

```
df2=df['ISSDTTM'].apply(lambda x:x[-1:-4])
```

Any approach to split this type of date formats? Should I use the dt.strformat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you were on the right track with `dt`. Coerce to datetime and use `dt.year`.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.ISSDTM, errors='coerce').dt.year

0    2013
1    2013
2    2009
3    2009
Name: ISSDTM, dtype: int64
```

You can use `DataFrame.plot.bar`, or `seaborn.countplot` to generate a count-plot.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post.I have more than 5,00,000 rows which is taking lot of time to process the data.And the data was actually converted into float 64 not int64

Comment: @HarshaVardhan It seems you have invalid datetimes, so those are coerced to NaT. Calling dt.year gives NaN. If you drop those rows, you can convert to int.

Comment: The dtype of year is converted into int64, but the values of the year are being shown as 2012.0,2013.0...? Do I need to cast this?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan try casting it and see, it may not be possible because of nans in your data.

Comment: df['ISSDTTM'].isnull().values.any()  is giving output as False. I think the column doesn't have missing data

Comment: @HarshaVardhan No worries, you can just convert to int using astype(int).